# How do I write compile time code in Swift?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, ios8

I'm wanting to write some compile-time code (i.e. code that is run when the project is compiled). This is used in other languages (e.g. Java) to write code generators (e.g. Dagger 2).

Is this possible in Swift? If so how? It is rather important for what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Swift per se.  You can generate source code using tools such as Python or Perl and integrate this into the Xcode build process

Comment: Why is this important for you to do? Possibly there's a better solution.

Comment: you want code generator written in Swift or code that generate Swift code?

Comment: @Paulw11 Are there examples of this? This might be a solution to what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: My apologies for the vagueness. The important part is I want to be able to inspect a few classes (a kind of reflection) at compile time and write automated code based off this.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague. There are multiple reasons for writing compile-time code, and it all depends on what you want to do.

If you want to write conditional code that only runs based on certain compile-time directives, use

```
#if build configuration
    statements
#else
    statements
#endif
```

If you want to generate code like a preprocessor would do in macros to reduce code duplication, then you should simply change your mindset and use swift functions and generics that will achieve the same result, only better. (Simple macros like `#define xxx ...` are replaced by `let xxx = ...`).

Finally, if you want to generate huge amounts of code then Swift isn't the language for you, you should use a dedicated code generator or some scripting language. For example, if you're looking to generate code for a state machine, use dedicated tools for that task that take as input UML. Obviously you'll have a hard time today finding tools that output Swift code (least of which being that Swift itself is a moving target), but that'll change over time.

Comment: cool! I have missed that the later betas added a limited 'precompiled' - nice - where can I read up on it?

Comment: In the docs about interacting with C apis. Not very intuitive :) https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html